# Как в QStandardItem добавить чекбокс

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется Qt 4.6. Требуется создать таблицу из 4 столбцов. Один из столбцов должен быть checkbox (по центру ячейки, без подписей). Как это реализовать - причём надо отслеживать нажатие-отжатие чекбокса.

Делаю как-то так:

```
QStandardItem* item0 = new QStandardItem(true);
item0->setCheckable(true);
item0->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
QList<QStandardItem*> row;
row.append(item0);
```

Но он никак не реагирует при нажатии и отжатии на него. Данные о его статусе не вытащить. Да и он в углу ячейки находится.

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете идиому Model/View. Содержимое ячейки (ваш чекбокс) относится к модели, а отображение этого чекбокса - к представлению.
Чтобы чекбокс оказался посередине ячейки, выровняйте ширину нужного столбца используемого представления по его содержимому (пример для `QTreeView`):

```
void QTreeView::resizeColumnToContents(int column);
```

Отследить переключение состояния чекбокса можно подключившись к сигналу модели:

```
void QStandardItemModel::itemChanged(QStandardItem* item);
```

В слоте получаете новое состояние чекбокса:

```
if (item->column() == YOUR_COLUMN) {
  if (item->isChackable() == true) {     // избыточная проверка на всякий случай
    bool isCheck = item->checkState() == Qt::Checked;
    // дальше делаете что вам нужно
  }
}
```